# "1 edit suggestions rejected"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, plurals

While checking one of my edit suggestion, I noticed a pluralisation “bug”. Here's a screenshot showing it:

> [image: Screenshot showing the “bug”]

I know this absolutely isn't high priority, but could it be fixed, please? I don't care if that results in getting a [giant S](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105).

Comment: Just reject an edit, problem solved...

Comment: Let me make a spam edit suggestion…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed - with you in the next build.

Comment: 17 minutes! It's that easy? Watch out; you're setting a dangerous precedent for pluralization fixes.

Comment: @mhlester - lots of these have become easier with our localization efforts.