# Incorrect use of the plural form ("one questions/answers")

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, stackexchange.com, plurals

This is a minor grammar quibble with respect to the UI.

Is it possible to add some logic to the Network Profile page, on the accounts tab, that changes the label "answers" to the singular "answer", in the case of there only being one question or answer?

> [image: Incorrect use of the plural form]

Admittedly this is a duplicate of the question [Wrong pluralization on accounts tab of user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125683/wrong-pluralization-on-accounts-tab-of-user-profile). The answer to that question was that it will not be fixed. However, the logic already exists elsewhere on the site. The logic required is [demonstrated here](https://serverfault.com/users/71823/ss-3-1415926535897932384626433). Here, you can find words "1 Question" & "1 Answer".

> [image: Correct example]

In addition, Oded's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/1-edit-suggestions-rejected#comment831410_254588) on his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/1-edit-suggestions-rejected#answer-254588) to the question [“1 edit suggestions rejected”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/1-edit-suggestions-rejected) suggests that it could quite easily be fixed now.

Comment: I believe pluralization  bugs can now be fixed but for the fun let me remind you of the [giant-s](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/158100)

Comment: This logic required is [demonstrated here](http://serverfault.com/users/71823/ss-3-1415926535897932384626433). Here, you can find words "1 Question" & "1 Answer".

Comment: Just let me share the prove that pluralization bugs can be fixed now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254585/1-edit-suggestions-rejected#comment831410_254588

Comment: @rene - Thanks for the link. I, rather pre-emptively voted to close the question as a duplicate, but then found the additional info, which I have now updated the post with. Should I, therefore, vote to reopen it?

Comment: Yeah, I think this deserves a chance but it should be a bug then, not a Feature request. The dupe is from 2012. Odeds comment proves that it is no longer by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this still can't be done, sorry.

On our Q&A sites, we use our in-house localisation platform, called MoonSpeak, to provide pluralisation support. However, the issue you're mentioning is on stackexchange.com, which is a separate product area from our Q&A sites. stackexchange.com does not currently use MoonSpeak, nor does it have any localisation support at present.